# Mongodb remove item from array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm trying to remove an element from an array using Java and haven't been successful...

I have a "emailsInApp" collection and inside I have this:

```
{ "_id" : "750afe", "list" : [ "John@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com" ] }
{ "_id" : "711850", "list" : [ "example@gmail.com" ] }
```

It holds for each id the registered emails.

What I would like to do is: given an id and an email, remove that email from that appId.

This is what I have atm and when I run it it doesn't change the array at all:

```
DBCollection emailsApp = db.getCollection(EmailsInAppColl);
BasicDBObject queryEmail = new BasicDBObject();
queryEmail.put("_id", appId);
BasicDBObject updateEmailCommand = new BasicDBObject();
updateEmailCommand.put("$pull", new BasicDBObject("list", email));
emailsApp.update(queryEmail, updateEmailCommand, true, true);
```

Could you point me in the right direction please?

Edit:
As reccomended by @Constantine if I debug it this is what I get:

```
DBCollection emailsApp = db.getCollection(EmailsInAppColl);
queryEmail.put("_id", appId);
DBCursor cursor = emailsApp.find(queryEmail);
System.out.println("######*****"+cursor.next());
```

In the console:

```
#####*****{ "_id" : "711850" , "list" : [ "example@gmail.com" , "peanut@gmail.com" , "chewie@gmail.com" , "gold@gmail.com"]}
```

The search query is correct but it does not remove the item...

Comment: Make sure you have the right collection name in the DBCollection parameter and check if the appId really exists. Please, debug it this way and tell if it is all correct.

Comment: Hi @Constantine, 
Thank you for the reply. 
I did test it using a cursor and it found the id.


So it is finding the app, the issue is removing the item...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something, like this:

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("_id", appId); //to match your direct app document
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("list", email);
coll.update(match, new BasicDBObject("$pull", update));
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Constantine. It happens I was thinking in the wrong way, I changed my array to have an id related to each email.

From there it is easier for me to maintain the array and solved the issue.

You help me find the right way :)