# Delete fields from array in mongodb using java driver

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I need delete all fields from the devices array they have the condition where `state = 0`

And this is my mongodb document:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53e53553b76000127cb1ab80"} ,  
  "city" : "Some Place" , 
  "devices" : 
       [ { "guid" : "local" , "brand" : "SSSS" , "state" : 1} , 
         { "guid" : "local2" , "brand" : "DDD" , "state" : 0} , 
         { "guid" : "local2" , "brand" : "DDD" , "state" : 0} ,   
         { "guid" : "local2" , "brand" : "DDD" , "state" : 0}] , 
  "phone": 8888888888,   
  "sex" : "Male"
 }
```

This is my java code that I'm trying:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(usersCollection);
BasicDBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);
((BasicDBObject) query2).append("devices.guid", device);
((BasicDBObject) query2).append("devices.state", 0);
collection.remove(query2);
```

But this query delete all devices from the document. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the problem following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061665/mongodb-remove-item-from-array)

This code works:

```
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(usersCollection);
    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);
    BasicDBObject update2 = new BasicDBObject("devices", new BasicDBObject("guid", device)
                                      .append("state", 0));
    collection.update(match, new BasicDBObject("$pull", update2));
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm mistaken, but that seems to be **exactly** what I wrote, except you declared the `BasicDBObject` containing `guid` and `state` inside the `update2` initialization, whereas I created the object and then put it into `update2`. Either way, it has an identical outcome. (Sorry if I missed something though, congrats on getting the answer!)

Comment: @Trust sorry but you answer was not useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the equivalent of:

```
db.usersCollection.update(
     {"_id":"yourId"}, 
     {$pull: 
            { "devices" : 
                    { $elemMatch : 
                        {
                          "guid":"local2", 
                          "state":"0"
                        }
                    }
            }
     }
)
```

*Where you replace the `yourId` with the ID you want to query*

That is, instead of using `remove`, use `update`, with `$pull` in the `BasicDBObject`. I can't test this right now but try:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(usersCollection);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);

BasicDBObject deviceToDelete = new BasicDBObject("guid",device);
deviceToDelete.append("state", "0");

BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("devices", deviceToDelete);
collection.update(query, new BasicDBObject("$pull",obj));
```

Let me know if this works (again I can't test because I don't have mongod on my machine).

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't delete anything in the document :/

Comment: What is the value of `device` (the variable you're passing into the `BasicDBObject`)?

Comment: Is "local2", corresponding to guid field

Comment: Can you tell me the output of printing `collection.findOne(query)`?

Comment: I replace for it: `db.usuario.findOne({devices:{"guid":"local2", "state":0}})` and get it : `null`

Comment: this `db.usersCollection.update({"_id":"yourId"}, {$pull: {devices:{"guid":"your guid", "state":"0"}}})`
 does nothing

Comment: Try looking here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/ and compare to my answer to see if I made a mistake anywhere. That's what I'm doing but I'm still not quite sure what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: Also look at my edit; try running the command with `$elemMatch`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the remove-Function to remove a embeded document, you need to use update instead. This is the function call you need to implement in java:

```
db.userCollection.update(
{_id: ObjectId("53e53553b76000127cb1ab80")},
{$pull: 
    { devices : 
            {state: 0}
    }
})
```

Notice that the update-function takes to arguments, the first one to find the document and the second one to modify it.

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(usersCollection);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", newObjectID("53e53553b76000127cb1ab80"));

BasicDBObject condition = new BasicDBObject("state",0);
BasicDBObject array = new BasicDBObject("devices", condition);
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$pull", array);

collection.update(query, update);
```

I didn't test the Java Code but I tested the function call in mongoDB. 
If it doesn't work, check the implementation first.